# Django FormView with dynamic forms

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views

I created the FormView below that will dynamically return a form class based on what step in the process that the user is in. I'm having trouble with the `get_form` method. It returns the correct form class in a get request, but the post request isn't working.

```
tournament_form_dict = {
    '1':TournamentCreationForm,
    '2':TournamentDateForm,
    '3':TournamentTimeForm,
    '4':TournamentLocationForm,
    '5':TournamentRestrictionForm,
    '6':TournamentSectionForm,
    '7':TournamentSectionRestrictionForm,
    '8':TournamentSectionRoundForm,}

class CreateTournament(FormView):
    template_name = 'events/create_tournament_step.html'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        super(CreateTournament, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, **kwargs):
        if 'step' not in kwargs:
             step = '1'
        else:
             step = kwargs['step']
        return tournament_form_dict[step]

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        if 'step' not in kwargs:
            step = 1
        else:
            step = int(kwargs['step'])
        step += 1
        if 'record_id' not in kwargs:
            record_id = 0
        else:
            record_id = int(kwargs['record_id'])
        return 'events/tournaments/create/%d/%d/' % (record_id, step)
```

The post request fails at the `django\views\generic\edit.py` at the `get_form` line, which I realize is because I've overwritten it in my FormView:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handle POST requests: instantiate a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then check if it's valid.
    """
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid(): â€¦
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

However, when I change the name of my custom `get_form` method to say `gen_form`, like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.gen_form()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    super(CreateTournament, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def gen_form(self, **kwargs):
    if 'step' not in kwargs:
        step = '1'
    else:
        step = kwargs['step']
    return tournament_form_dict[step]
```

my form class doesn't get processed in the get request and evaluates to `None`. I'm scratching my head as to why when I override the `get_form` method, it works, but my own named method doesn't? Does anyone know what the flaw might be?

Comment: Yes, the `get_form` is a function defined in `FormView`, and thus you use that one. In fact except for the `super(...)` call, your `__init__` function is not doing anything, since you only use *local* variables.

Comment: So I need to: `self.form_class` it?

Comment: yes, furthermore I advice to use `reverse` to "calculate" the URL instead of doing list formatting yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Comment: okay thanks...there are still aspects to python/django that just don't seem intuitive to me...but maybe I just don't know it well enough...I'll try that. thanks

Comment: I found it helpful to read some documentation. For a lot of tools, documentation is not much high-quality. But I have to say that people writing (most) of the Django docs did a good job. After a while, you are more familiar with the "feel" of Django, and therefore after a while can "predict" how something is designed.

Comment: I have read through it...and while I agree that it's an excellent source and exhaustive, I do find myself missing simple python principles at times which I will chalk up to not working in python too often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's [**`FormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#formmixin) defines a [**`get_form`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form). You here thus basically subclassed the `FormView` and "patched" the `get_form` method.

Your attempt with the `gen_form` does not work, since you only defined *local* variables, and thus do not make much difference anyway, only the `super(..)` call will have some side effects. The other commands will keep the CPU busy for some time, but at the end, will only assign a reference to a `Form` calls to the `form_class` variable, but since it is local, you will throw it away.

That being said, your function contains some errors. For example the `**kwargs` will usually contain *at most* one parameter: `form_class`. So the `step`s will not do much. You can access the URL parameters through `self.args` and `self.kwargs`, and the querystring parameters through `self.request.GET`. Furthermore you probably want to patch the [**`get_form_class`** function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class) anyway, since you return a reference to a class, not, as far as I understand it, a reference to an initilized form.

Constructing URLs through string processing is probably not a good idea either, since if you would (slightly) change the URL pattern, then it is likely you will forget to replace the `success_url`, and hence you will refer to a path that no longer exists. Using the [**`reverse`** function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) is a safer way, since you pass the name of the view, and parameters, and then this function will "calculate" the correct URL. This is basically the mechanism behind the `{% url ... %}` template tag in Django templates.

A better approach is thus:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class CreateTournament(FormView):
    template_name = 'events/create_tournament_step.html'

    def get_form_class(self):
        return tournament_form_dict[self.kwargs.get('step', '1')]

    def get_success_url(self):
        new_step = int(self.kwargs.get('step', 1)) + 1
        # use a reverse
        return reverse('name_of_view', kwargs={'step': new_step})
```